# Oracle Sql Delete with row number throws error ORA-00904: "RN": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, select, oracle12c, sql-delete, row-number

I am trying to delete from a table using select & row number but it is throwing me error at the last line.

```
delete from ZZ_temp_Value where (nach_id,vv_lfd,language,value,dq_nr,emptyvalue,unit) IN 
(select  t.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY vv_lfd ORDER BY emptyvalue,position) rn 
     from 
       (select distinct w.*, q.position 
        from ZZ_temp_Value w, zz_def d, dv_format q 
         on q.nach_id = w.nach_id
        and q.vv_lfd = w.vv_lfd
      order by  w.emptyvalue, q.position)t
       where t.rn < 1 ;
```

Or i wanted to delete the value from this select in table ZZ_temp_Value where the row number is not 1.

```
select  t.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY vv_lfd ORDER BY emptyvalue,position) rn 
         from 
           (select distinct w.*, q.position 
            from ZZ_temp_Value w, zz_def d, dv_format q 
             on q.nach_id = w.nach_id
            and q.vv_lfd = w.vv_lfd
          order by  w.emptyvalue, q.position
```

Comment: the last line of `where t.rn < 1` translates to less than 1

Comment: Please post exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

Several syntax and logic issues abound in your attempted query:

- **ON Clause**: Using an `ON` clause without a matching `JOIN`. Your query can possibly work if `ON` is replaced by `WHERE` which is the older, deprecated way of joining tables in SQL known as the [implicit join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins).
- **Cross Join**: As is the drawback of the implicit join, you mistakenly (or intentionally?) did not join `zz_def d` with matched columns. While you match `q` and `w`, not matching `d` rendered a cross join on that table to return more rows than desired. Also, `d` is not used in `SELECT`.
- **Misaligned Subquery**: Layered subqueries show a missing closing parenthesis where you misaligned table alias `t` that references calculated column, `rn`, at a different level.
- **WHERE Logic**: Since `ROW_NUMBER` returns positive values, your logical condition `t.RN < 1` may return no results once syntax errors are resolved.

Additionally, consider a few tips:

- **Explicit Join**: Use the explicit `JOIN` to join tables and avoid the subtle mistake of running a cross join.
- **SELECT `*`**: Avoid using [SELECT *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful) to better control presentation and visibly show selected columns. Specifically, no where are the following columns shown in subquery: `nach_id, language, value, dq_nr` which you intend to match to outer query.
- **Column Aliases**: Alias all columns in `SELECT` to visibly show sources to tables. Specifically, your window function does not explicitly reference table sources of columns. Ideally, you would run `PARTITION BY w.vv_lfd ORDER BY w.emptyvalue, q.position`.
- **Table Aliases**: Use better table aliases than the letters chosen to avoid code readers to scan back to `FROM` and `JOIN` clauses for their original sources. Ideally,

  ```
  from ZZ_temp_Value t ... zz_def d ... dv_format f

  from ZZ_temp_Value tmp ... zz_def def ... dv_format fmt
  ```

---

Assuming your ultimate need is to delete rows where the row number is *greater* than 1 really (`rn > 1`), consider adjusted query (that would need testing).

```sql
DELETE FROM ZZ_temp_Value 
WHERE (nach_id, vv_lfd, language, value, dq_nr, emptyvalue, unit) IN 
  (SELECT t.nachi, t.vvlfd, t.language, t.value, t.dq_nr, t.emptyvalue, t.unit 
   FROM 
     (SELECT tmp.nachi, tmp.vv_lfd, tmp.language, tmp.value
             , tmp.dq_nr, tmp.emptyvalue, tmp.unit 
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tmp.vv_lfd 
                                  ORDER BY tmp.emptyvalue, fmt.position) rn
      FROM ZZ_temp_Value tmp
      INNER JOIN dv_format fmt
          ON  fmt.vv_lfd = tmp.vv_lfd
          AND fmt.nach_id = tmp.nach_id
      -- CROSS JOIN zz_def d                     -- CAREFULLY THINK ABOUT THIS! 
     ) t
   WHERE t.rn > 1
  );
```

`DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY` have been removed being redundant. `ROW_NUMBER()` would repeat for duplicate records and subquery ordering of rows is ignored for outer query results.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but i get error in the line -- > where t.rn > 1 since we are not selecting t.rn in the select statement it throws an error saying ORA-00904: "RN": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: Odd. I know Oracle has rules of deeply nested subqueries but as positioned, `rn` should exist for `WHERE` condition (which logically runs before `SELECT`). Try running the subquery (i.e., two sub-`SELECT`s) by itself outside of `DELETE`. Same error?